# Preg_match_all to also return initial values

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

If I made regular expression and pass array `$content` to it:

```
preg_match_all(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/, $content, $matches);
```

Where `$content` is array:

```
Name Address 77/88 Country
Name Address 71/90 Country
Name Address 72/43 Country
Name Address 76/55 Country
Name Country
Name Address
```

It will return `$matches`:

```
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "77/88"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "71/90"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "72/43"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "76/55"
  }
```

But can I get somehow the initial array `$content` values too with matched values?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$content` will need to be a string for `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/^.*?([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+).*$/m', $content, $matches);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name Address 77/88 Country
            [1] => Name Address 71/90 Country
            [2] => Name Address 72/43 Country
            [3] => Name Address 76/55 Country
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 77
            [1] => 71
            [2] => 72
            [3] => 76
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 88
            [1] => 90
            [2] => 43
            [3] => 55
        )
)
```

If `$content` really is an array:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/', $content);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name Address 77/88 Country
    [1] => Name Address 71/90 Country
    [2] => Name Address 72/43 Country
    [3] => Name Address 76/55 Country
)
```